# Fluid simulation not looking realistic: Fluid runs up the walls of the volume

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was running this for the third time and I am always getting a similiar result: A huge part of the fluid runs up the walls instead of filling the volume.

I have attached a picture showing the mesh and another showing my fluid settings.

Please can someone help me with this issue or give me some realistic looking settings?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thing - as with all simulations - is to check your scale. Make sure your meshes are at a realistic scale and that you have ‘Applied Scale’ on any that have been resized, then re-bake your simulation.

Comment: If you just want to fill the cup then make the liquid domain a lot smaller so it just fits the cup and the area above it. Then place the inflow object over the cup and inside the domain. The cup must be an effector (collision) to get filled.

Comment: we cannot see the size of your inflow/geometry...so might be a good help for us if you would provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: @RichSedman OK I've never tried it with 'Applied Scale' (you mean apply scale by pressing cntrl+A I assume?)

Comment: @fabmeyer Yes - that’s the one. It’s something you should always do for meshes that are interacting with simulations - otherwise it can behave as if it’s a different physical size. It’s hard to tell what’s going on in your screenshot. It would be good if you could add an animated gif showing the movement and describe the starting conditions and what you’re expecting it to do.

Comment: @RichSedman OK thanks I will rerun it again with applied scale... Then will post or answer here again. Does the inflow object also need applied scale?

Comment: You might get away without applying scale to everything - including the inflows - but, TBH, it’s not worth not applying scale to it just to rule it out as an issue. It could be that the simulation code uses the scale when determining the inflow velocity - in which case a wrong scale could potentially make the fluid get generated at a wildly different initial velocity. Apply scale on everything (inflow, outflow, effector, domain) just to be sure. It’s good practice to generally apply scale even when just modelling - so won’t cause any harm.